# Consultar usando o Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Sou iniciante no Entity Framework e logo de cara peguei um software para manutenção que usa o Entity.

Preciso criar um relatório e fazer a seguinte busca SQL usando o Entity:

```
select p.RA, p.Nome, p.Modulo, a.Descricao  from inscricao as i, Participante as p, Atividade as a
where i.ParticipanteId = p.ParticipanteId and 
       i.AtividadeId = a.AtividadeId
order by p.Modulo
```

E no Controller eu uso o seguinte método "tentei" fazer a busca citada acima usando o Entity.

```
public ActionResult ParticipantesInscritosAtividade(RelatorioParticipantesInscritosAtividadeVM ViewModel) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var participantes = db.Inscricoes
                    .Join(db.Participantes, ins => ins.ParticipanteId, pa => pa.ParticipanteId, (ins, pa) => new { ins, pa })
                    .Join(db.Atividades, ins1 => ins1.ins.AtividadeId, atv => atv.AtividadeId, (ins1, atv) => new { ins1, atv })
                    .Select(query => new
                    {
                        ParticipanteId = query.ins1.pa.ParticipanteId,
                        RA = query.ins1.pa.RA,
                        Aluno = query.ins1.pa.Nome,
                        AtividadeId = query.atv.AtividadeId,
                        Atividade = query.atv.Titulo,
                        Modulo = query.ins1.pa.Modulo
                    }).ToList();

       if(participantes.Count() == 0) {
            ViewModel.Mensagens.Add(new MensagemVM { Mensagem = MessageUtils.MESSAGE_NO_REPORT_DATA, TipoMensagem = MensagemVM.TipoMensagemEnum.Warning });
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var p in participantes)
            {
                 ViewModel.Participantes.Add(new RelParticipantesInscritosAtividadeVM { RA = p.ins1.pa.RA.Value, Nome =  p.ins1.pa.Nome , Modulo = p.ins1.pa.Modulo.v });
            }
        }
    }

    PrepararRelatorioParticipantesInscritosAtividadeViewModel(ViewModel);
    return View(ViewModel);
}
```

Quando faço isso o ModelState.isValid retorna que o objeto não pode receber um valor nulo.

Meu model está assim:

```
public class RelParticipantesInscritosAtividadeVM
{
    [Display(Name = "R.A.")]
    public long RA { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Modulo")]
    public int Modulo { get; set; }
}
```

Não tem campo required e mesmo assim o Model.isValid continua dando o erro.

O meu SQL é só um exemplo do que preciso fazer, usando o Join eu realizei a consulta mas não sta retornando os valores corretos, peço ajuda a traduzi meu SQL para o Entity,

```
public class RelatorioParticipantesInscritosAtividadeVM
{
    public RelatorioParticipantesInscritosAtividadeVM()
    {
        this.Participantes = new List<RelParticipantesInscritosAtividadeVM>();
        this.Mensagens = new List<MensagemVM>();

    }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Data")]
//    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [UIHint("DataGeral")]
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Período")]
  //  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    public Rel2PeriodoEnumVM Periodo { get; set; }
    public SelectList PeriodosList { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Curso")]
   // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    public string CursoId { get; set; }
    public SelectList CursosList { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Atividade")]
  //  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    public String AtividadeId { get; set; }
    public SelectList AtividadeList { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Termo")]
  //  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    public short Termo { get; set; }
    public SelectList TermosList { get; set; }



    public IList<RelParticipantesInscritosAtividadeVM> Participantes { get; set; }
    public IList<MensagemVM> Mensagens { get; set; }
  //  public IList<RelAtividadeVM> Atividade { get; set; }

}
```

}

Como sugerido, criei um breakpoint no linha solicitada mas consta que a variavel não existe no contexto atual. Ao ir para a próxima linha (F11), dá esse famigerado erro:

> O objeto nulo deve ter um valor.
>
> Descrição: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da
>   atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter
>   mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> Detalhes da Exceção: System.InvalidOperationException: O objeto nulo
>   deve ter um valor.
>
> Erro de Origem:
>
> Linha 113:            { Linha 114: Linha 115:            var errors =
>   ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors); Linha 116:            if
>   (ModelState.IsValid) Linha 117:                {

Comment: O erro é porque alguma propriedade do seu model está como obrigatória (`Required`) e está recebendo _null_.

Comment: O seu exemplo SQL sequer esta fazendo um join. Como o amigo disse, ModelState.IsValid não tem a ver com a consulta, ele nem chega próximo de fazer a consulta.

Comment: O model que você recebe no método e ele diz que é inválido é o RelatorioParticipantesInscritosAtividadeVM (não o que você colocou acima)

Comment: de qualquer forma, você sabe qual o campo que ele critica?
coloca um _breakpoint_ no `.IsValid`, o cursor do mouse no `ModelState` e vai em `Values`.. lá você tem todas as propriedades e dentro de cada uma a indicação se tem ou não erro. Pega qual o índice da que tem erro e vê em `Keys` qual é a que tá com problema. 
Espero que ajude.

Comment: Fiz como você me pediu: Tenho 5 keys e 5 values e não está apresentado erro. MInhas keys são Data, Periodo, CursoId, atividadeId e Termo

Comment: @RafaelChristófano, coloca a mensagem de erro então, pra ver se tem algo que passou batido

Comment: Usa esse código: `var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);` e veja qual os erros esta acontecendo

Comment: Você chegou a verificar se o objeto "ViewModel" não está nulo? Pode ser que seu problema esteja na requisição..

Comment: O ViewModel está passando todas as informações setadas na view.